# How can one run Adobe Fresco in a virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, adobe-fresco

When I try to run Adobe Fresco in a virtual machine, I get:

[image]

How can one run Adobe Fresco in a virtual machine?

The `learn more` [page](https://helpx.adobe.com/fresco/system-requirements.html) points  to some GPU requirements that I don't know how to achieve in a virtual machine.

I'm ok to use any VM and hypervisor.

---

From System Information:

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Processor | 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11900H @ 2.50GHz, 2496 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s) |
| Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions | Yes |
| Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions | Yes |
| Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware | Yes |
| Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection | Yes |

Comment: You are totally wrong @Ramhound. The hypervisor DOES NOT need to support the DX12_1

The only the GPU needs to. You aren't making any sense. I've literally got Maxwell GPU's running in VM's. When running in VM's they still are 12_1 capable.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, so what's missing is the information on which hardware I use?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - your processor model.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a VM that has a physical GPU passed into the VM.

Depending on your software, you might require two GPU's to achieve this.

There are a lot of people who do this using a single GPU however they generally use Linux to achieve this.

A good place to start learning about how to do this is on the following reddit sub. https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/

EDIT: To expand on this

You will need a CPU that supports VT-d (or the AMD equilivent) and a hypervisor that supports hardware passthrough.

This is different to say VMWare Workstation or VT-G in that instead of using a special driver to rewrite the GPU functions onto the hypervisor, it "plugs" the physical hardware into the VM making it unavailable to the host.

From the point of view of the VM it has the physical GPU attached to its PCIe bus. This means that the VM is able to have full access to the hardware capabilities of the GPU.

This can be done on ESXi (vsphere) but obviously this renders the machine running the VM unavailable for anything else.

I've done this on ProxMox, but it's also the same in that the hypervisor isn't intended to be used as a desktop AND run VM's.

You can do this easily on Linux using KVM. When the VM is running it will have full control of the GPU it is using, so if you wish to retain your normal desktop while running the VM you will need two GPU's.

I am unsure if the non-server (desktop) versions of Hyper-V are able to do hardware passthrough. I generally don't use Hyper-V as it's consistently slower and less flexible than other solutions. But I do know its possible with the server versions.

Feel free to reach out to me, or other people, in the subreddit I mentioned. We love to help.

Comment: Not exactly true. They have always claimed that the Error 43 issue was accidental. The functionality that was restricted to the high end cards was supporting SR-IOV that allowed you to split a card into multiple cards. EDIT: Oh and headless GPU functionality. That was restricted to their Tesla GRID licensed cards. Those are fun.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, Adobe Fresco prelease 4.3.0 does run into a regular virtual machine:

[image]

Unlike Adobe Fresco 4.1.1:

[image]